# Animate a div from offscreen, without absolute positions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a scoreboard... This scoreboard is a series of inline-block divs to keep it horizontal:

```
<div class="top">

    <div class="score1 color0 inline slow">
        <div class="inner color3 slow">
            <div class="title">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="player1 color0 inline slow">
        <div class="inner color2 slow">
            <div class="title">KDZaster</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="round color0 inline slow">
        <div class="inner color1 slow">
            <div class="title">Grand Finals</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="player2 color0 inline slow">
        <div class="inner color2 slow">
            <div class="title">DarthArma</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="score2 color0 inline slow">
        <div class="inner color3 slow">
            <div class="title">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have included a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lsxhmky7/

This page has a whole bunch of animations that I am doing with both CSS and jQuery (which are not included in the jsFiddle)... I've got all the animations working, except one.

One of the things I would like to do is so that the two score arrows on the left and right sides slide in from the edges of the screen.

I know I can do this with absolute positioning, but this grid doesn't have anything else in absolute positions, and I don't want it to be. I want it to be inline so that if widths of certain elements have to change, the page moves with it.

Is there a way I can animate the moving of these two elements from offscreen, while maintaining the inline positioning of all other blocks?

Comment: I think it can be achieved by using transform translate. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: @HayleyKiara you're the best! Can you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Nevermind. It's okay. Just leave it there ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fairly simple with `transform: translate();`

Move the arrow offscreen by default using transformX, then animate it moving back into position.

`animation: slideInLeft 2s 1 forwards;`

animation: [name] [length] [iterations] [end]

This runs the animation only once, for 2 seconds then stops at the end state.

```
.score1 {
    width: var(--score-width);
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
        0 0,
        0 calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
        0 var(--main-height),
        calc(var(--score-width) - var(--arrow-width)) var(--main-height),
        var(--score-width) calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
        calc(var(--score-width) - var(--arrow-width)) 0
    );
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  animation: slideInLeft 2s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from { transform: translate(-100px); }
  to { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

Reverse for the right arrow.

```css
:root {
 --main-color0: rgba(000,000,000,0.5);
 --main-color1: rgba(255,000,000,0.5);
 --main-color2: rgba(000,255,255,0.5);
 --main-color3: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 
 --main-height: 50px;
 --main-gutter: -10px;
 --main-padding: 10px;
 --main-border: 4px;
 
 --font-family: 'Franklin Gothic';
 --font-color: #FFFFFF;
 --font-large: 24px;
 --font-small: 14px;
 --font-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000;

 --arrow-width: 15px;
 --round-width: 180px;
 --player-width: 300px;
 --score-width: 50px;
 
 --out-speed: 0.5s;
 --in-speed: 2s;
}

body {
 color: var(--font-color);
 font-family: var(--font-family);
 font-size: var(--font-large);
 text-shadow: var(--font-shadow);
 line-height: var(--main-height);

 margin: 10px 0;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.slow { transition: all var(--in-speed) ease; }
.fast { transition: all var(--out-speed) linear; }
.inline { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 -7px; }
.inner { -webkit-clip-path: inset(var(--main-border) 0); }

.color0 { background-color: var(--main-color0); }
.color1 { background-color: var(--main-color1); }
.color2 { background-color: var(--main-color2); }
.color3 { background-color: var(--main-color3); }

.title {
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.round {
 font-size: var(--font-small);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: var(--round-width);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
  var(--arrow-width) 0,
  0 calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
  var(--arrow-width) var(--main-height),
  calc(var(--round-width) - var(--arrow-width)) var(--main-height),
  var(--round-width) calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
  calc(var(--round-width) - var(--arrow-width)) 0
 );
}

.player1 {
 width: var(--player-width);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
  0 0,
  var(--arrow-width) calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
  0 var(--main-height),
  var(--player-width) var(--main-height),
  calc(var(--player-width) - var(--arrow-width)) calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
  var(--player-width) 0
 );
}
.player2 {
 width: var(--player-width);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
  0 0,
  var(--arrow-width) calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
  0 var(--main-height),
  var(--player-width) var(--main-height),
  calc(var(--player-width) - var(--arrow-width)) calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
  var(--player-width) 0
 );
}
.player1 .title { padding: 0 20px; text-align: right; }
.player2 .title { padding: 0 20px; text-align: left; }



.score1 {
 width: var(--score-width);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
  0 0,
  0 calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
  0 var(--main-height),
  calc(var(--score-width) - var(--arrow-width)) var(--main-height),
  var(--score-width) calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
  calc(var(--score-width) - var(--arrow-width)) 0
 );
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  animation: slideInLeft 2s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from { transform: translate(-100px); }
  to { transform: translateX(0); }
}
.score2 {
 width: var(--score-width);
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
  var(--arrow-width) 0,
  0 calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
  var(--arrow-width) var(--main-height),
  var(--score-width) var(--main-height),
  var(--score-width) calc(var(--main-height) / 2),
  var(--score-width) 0
 );
}

.score1 .title { padding: 0 20px 0 0; text-align: right; }
.score2 .title { padding: 0 0 0 20px; text-align: left; }
```

```html
 <div class="top">
  
  <div class="score1 color0 inline slow">
   <div class="inner color3 slow">
    <div class="title">0</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="player1 color0 inline slow">
   <div class="inner color2 slow">
    <div class="title">KDZaster</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="round color0 inline slow">
   <div class="inner color1 slow">
    <div class="title">Grand Finals</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="player2 color0 inline slow">
   <div class="inner color2 slow">
    <div class="title">DarthArma</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="score2 color0 inline slow">
   <div class="inner color3 slow">
    <div class="title">0</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with good ol' `position: relative`:

```
.score1 {
    position: relative;
    right: calc(var(--score-width) + var(--arrow-width));
}
```

Using `transition`/`animation` you can also do without jQuery.

Alternatively you can use `transform: translate(...)`, or even better `translateX(...)` which triggers 3D transformations and thus the load will probably end on the GPU rather than the CPU, possibily yielding better performances.